# View contents of magnet URL via command line?

Tags: command-line, bittorrent

Is there any way to view the contents of a magnet URL using command line?

I've tried `aria2c` which can view the contents of a torrent file but doesn't seem to show contents of magnet URLs.

Answer (score 16):

Magnet link doesn't contains any information about files. At first you should download torrent and then you can extract information. E.g. you can use [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/) utility. Here is bash wrapper function:

```
magnet-info() {
  hash=$(echo "$1" | grep -oP "(?<=btih:).*?(?=&)")
  echo "Magnet hash: $hash"
  aria2c --bt-metadata-only=true --bt-save-metadata=true -q "$1"
  aria2c "$hash.torrent" -S
}
```

That function will download torrent to `$hash.torrent` file and then display it's content.

Usage example:

```
$ magnet-info "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:64b7700828fd44b37c0c045091939a2c0258ddc2&dn=archlinux-2014.06.01-dual.iso&tr=udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969&tr=http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce"
Magnet hash: 64b7700828fd44b37c0c045091939a2c0258ddc2
>>> Printing the contents of file '64b7700828fd44b37c0c045091939a2c0258ddc2.torrent'...
*** BitTorrent File Information ***
Mode: single
Announce:
 udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969
 http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce
Info Hash: 64b7700828fd44b37c0c045091939a2c0258ddc2
Piece Length: 512KiB
The Number of Pieces: 1094
Total Length: 547MiB (573,571,072)
Name: archlinux-2014.06.01-dual.iso
Magnet URI: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:64B7700828FD44B37C0C045091939A2C0258DDC2&dn=archlinux-2014.06.01-dual.iso&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.archlinux.org%3A6969&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.archlinux.org%3A6969%2Fannounce
Files:
idx|path/length
===+===========================================================================
  1|./archlinux-2014.06.01-dual.iso
   |547MiB (573,571,072)
---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```